# Changing Material UI's H1 with createMuiTheme

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, material-ui

I am after creating a custom theme with material UI but cannot target individual parts of the theme as I would like:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#556cd6',
      fontFamily: '"Indie Flower", handwriting',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
    background: {
      default: '#fff',
    },
  },
  typography: {
    // Use the system font instead of the default Roboto font.
    h1: {
      fontFamily: '"Indie Flower", handwriting',
    },
  },
})
```

Are you able to change things like default font for `h1,h2,input,p` etc?

Comment: Your syntax here seems fine (though the fontFamily within the palette won't do anything). Please show the code that uses the Typography element that isn't using the font you expect. A code sandbox reproducing the problem would be ideal.

Comment: My answer here has a working sandbox using a similar theme: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367081/how-do-i-set-custom-fonts-for-header-body-and-button-tags-for-material-ui/55367542#55367542